# Achieve values in one line

Tags: batch

Is it possible to combine these two script lines into one ?

```
For /f  "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('WMIC computersystem get manufacturer /Value^|Find /i "Manufacturer="') Do Set Maker=%%A
For /f  "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('WMIC computersystem get model /Value^|Find /i "Model="') Do Set name=%%A
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

REVISED
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It declare two variables named "Manufacturer" and "Model" with the appropriate value :

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%e in ('wmic computersystem get manufacturer^, model /Value ^| find "=" ') do set %%e=%%f
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to extract the values after the equal sign ! See screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To use the names chosen for the variables, the option would be to add an `if defined` and change the output format to `format:xlm` , filtering the value in the strings.

```bath
for /f useback^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%i in (`wmic computersystem get manufacturer^,model /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do if defined _Maker (set "_name=%%~i")else set "_Maker=%%~i"
```

---

> *Thanks but I want to extract the values after the equal sign ! See screenshot. –
> [`VB88`](https://superuser.com/users/1665489/vb88)*
> Use `/format:table` in `wmic` command:

```bath
for /f tokens^=1* %%i in ('wmic computersystem get manufacturer^,model /format:table^|findstr .')do set "Maker=%%~i" & set "name=%%~j"
```